# Is it possible to add a time clause to the license of an intellectual work?

Tags: copyright-notice

Would it be possible (and legal) to add the following copyright notice to an intellectual work (for example, a book):

> All rights reserved until January 1st 2030 and CC-BY license from this date.

From what I understand, you can put anything in a copyright notice as long as the restrictions are less than what is required by law, but I don't know much about intellectual property law.

I am a citizen of the European Union (France).

Comment: the CC people do not like their trademark used on licenses thatr are modified versions of their licenses, so you might not be able to use the words 'CC-By". But the concept of their license is free for anyone to use.

Comment: Same for GPL. We really, really don't want any licenses around that look like GPL and have been subtly modified.

Comment: You can add restrictions that are harder than what copyright law allows me to do. They are just not useful if copyright law allows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why one couldn't. I'm not sure that it would be wise, but it would probably be permissible.

The only hard question would be if the license could be revoked before that date if there was no consideration paid for the license and if no one had justifiably relied upon the grant of license. The grant of license would probably not be irrevocable if revoked before the date stated, although it might be hard to give notice to all affected parties to make the revocation binding as to all of them.

Comment: "I'm not sure that it would be wise" might you elaborate? I am curious of what you had in mind

Comment: @Laravel I would never recommend giving something away in advance because people change their minds much more often than they think they will and it is easy to change your mind in the other direction later on.

Comment: In other words, give it away on 1st January 2030. Unless you change your mind in the next eight years.